# How do you unlock the Dream Suite?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How do I unlock the Dream Suite in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Answer (score 7):

In order to unlock the Dream Suite, you have to enter the Town Hall and catch Isabelle in the middle of a nap. After waking her up, she'll suggest that you build the Dream Suite. It will cost 234,000 Bells.

The requirements for this are:

- It's been at least 7 days since you've unlocked public works
- You've then completed at least one public works project
- You've connected to the Internet at least once

Answer (score 1):

According to [animal crossing new leaf wikispaces,](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Dream+Suite)

> To unlock the Dream Suite as a public works project, the player must find Isabelle asleep at the town hall. This happens when you have been mayor for at least seven days, and have played on WiFi. She will then wake up and tell the player that a visitor (Luna) has requested the Dream Suite as a community project. It costs 234,000 Bells to build and will open on Main Street, in a preexisting building.

Answer (score 0):

In order to unlock the Dream Suite, you have to enter the Town Hall and catch Isabelle in the middle of a nap. After waking her up, she'll suggest that you build the Dream Suite. It will cost 234,000 Bells.

The requirements for this are:

It's been at least 7 days since you've unlocked public works
You've then completed at least one public works project
You've connected to the Internet at least once